# Paths with trailing slashes being rendered incorrectly in chat

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, chat, markdown

Consider the following markdown:

```
`C:\`
```

In chat, this is rendered as follows:

[image]

Instead of the expected output:

```
C:\
```

Using two slashes doesn't help:

[image]

Although the slash appears, the text is not rendered in a monospace font and the backticks are shown.

Comment: What is this, code blocks on non-code elements!? That's your *real* problem!

Comment: I just had a peek at the MarkdownMini code, backslashes inside backticks are treated specially to enable backticks to appear in code sections. e.g., `\`((pi . ,(acos -1)))`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use double backticks:

```
``c:\``
```

This renders correctly in chat:

[image]

Tested in the [chat sandbox](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1/sandbox):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think this is probably a bug with Chat.SE's version of markdown. Take the following example message:

> ```
> `\`
> ```

Instead of rendering as inline code, like `\`, as you'd expect, it renders like this:

> [image]

Which is clearly not the desired behavior. If you *really* want to render file paths that end in `\`, you can just indent them by four spaces, as seen below. Note the lack of backticks.

> ```
>    Blah foo baz C:\Foobar\ spam eggs.
> ```

Do note, your entire message will be formatted like code though.